# How many 8 digit even numbers greater than 40,000,000 can be formed using all the digits: 2,3,3,4,7,7,7,9

Tags: permutations

So what I’ve currently done is break it down into the following ends:
4_______2
4_______4

And etc, creating endings that would fit the question in asking for numbers that are both larger, and even. But I’m not sure how to proceed with the rest?

Is there a proper approach rather than guessing?

Comment: Umm.... why not, say, $9________2$?

Comment: I do not want to use guesswork, but that is already in my list of possible start and endings.

Comment: @JamesBaxter I don't think you understand David G. Stork's comment.

Comment: @JackyChong.  You're right, he doesn't understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: Care to explain it then?

Comment: How is 4_______4 possible?

Comment: @JamesBaxter The point David G. Stork is making is that your initial list of ends is incomplete because an acceptable number also can start with $7$ or $9$.  So it's not good enough to count just the combinations you've listed.  Also, since you're only supplied $8$ digits and you need to end up with an eight-digit number, you can't repeat $4$.

Comment: I would have liked to answer this question but I do not see your working other than a statement that you split into cases, without listing all cases and without showing your work.

Comment: Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself even if the method is not the most efficient. In any case, one approach would be to simply count all possible even numbers (which is straightforward) and then subtract all even numbers that start with $2$ or $3$ - again easy to count.

Comment: Hint: lead 9, lead 7, lead 4. $\binom{6}{3\,2\,1}\cdot2+\binom{6}{1\,2\,2\,1}\cdot2+\binom{6}{1\,3\,2}$